# Derivative of $F(x) = \int^{x}_0\frac{(x-t)^n}{n!}e^tdt$

Tags: integration, derivatives, power-series

This comes from my maths text book in the proof for the power series of $e^x$. At the start of the exercise, I am supposed to show that $e^x = \sum\limits_{k=0}^{n}{\frac{x^n}{n!}}$ $+ \int^{x}_0\frac{(x-t)^n}{n!}e^tdt$. While the textbook goes through a lengthy proof by induction, I thought I could be smart and show that the R.H.S differentiates back to itself, and, since the R.H.S satisfies the boundary condition of passing through $(0,1)$,  that the R.H.S = $e^x$ through the unicity of the exponential. The definition of the exponential I am using is the unique function which satisfies $f'=f$ and $f(0) = 1$.

The problem with this approach is that I don't know how to differentiate the integral. It should be $\frac{x^n}{n!}$, but I can't seem to prove it.

Here is what I tried:

Let $F(x) = \int^{x}_0\frac{(x-t)^n}{n!}e^tdt$

Let $f(t) = \frac{(x-t)^n}{n!}e^t$ ( x here is treated as some constant)

Let $G(t)$ be some antiderivative of $f$. This means that, when differentiating with respect to t, $G'(t) = f(t)$

Then $F(x) = G(x) - G(0)$ (Fundamental theorem of calculus)

And so $F'(x) = G'(x) - G'(0)$ (Differentiate with respect to x)

Note that $G'(x) ≠ f(x) $ as the function $f$ contains some x's. Similarly $G'(0) ≠ 0 $

How do I get around this?

I've also realized that, if I suppose $G'(x) = f(x)$ and $G'(0) = f(0)$, then we get $F'(x) = -\frac{x^n}{n!}$ which is frustratingly close to the actual answer, just off by a minus sign.

Please forgive me if I am using wrong mathematics terminology, I am only  16-year old and so my mathematics writing skills are not yet very good.

**Question** :  Find the derivative (w.r.t to x) of $F(x) = \int^{x}_0\frac{(x-t)^n}{n!}e^tdt$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**

Set $$G(x,y)=\int_0^x\frac{(y-t)^n}{n!}e^{-t}\,\mathrm d t,$$

and let $p(u)=G(u,u)$. Compute $p'(u)$.

Comment: I am not familiar with calculus with multiple variables. Could you point me out to the formula/concept needed to differentiate $G(u,u)$?

Comment: @SomeProgrammer the multivariable chain rule is what you'll want to use here

Answer (score 3):

$F(x)=\int_0^{x} \frac {u^{n}} {n!} e^{x-u}du$ by the substitution $u=x-t$. This gives $F(x)=e^{x} \int_0^{x} \frac {u^{n}} {n!} e^{-u}du$. Now differentiate using product rule.

Comment: This is very nice! Thank you for your help.